# SHA1 with a passphrase, no passwords involved

Tags: php, encryption, web, passphrase

I am retrieving a session id and key from a remote server that I do not have root access to. I would like to encrypt this data for my own reasons, and when I have to send the keys back to the API server for w/e, I need to decrypt. As I understand it, you cannot just decrypt an SHA hash. Is there a way to pass the session info to an encrypted variable with a specific passphrase, or "decrypt key", that will later allow me to decrypt?

I have searched, and googled the subject. All it turns up are people looking to decrypt passwords stored in SHA1. This is not a noob attempt to learn how to brute force/collide a hash. I have a legit purpose for this.

Comment: A "password" and "passphrase" are the same thing, except one is longer, so your title is somewhat nonsensical. What you are trying to do is possible, but has nothing to do with SHA1 or other hashing functions. You can not "decrypt" SHA1 because it is *not encrypted*, it's hashed, which is inherently an irreversible operation. You need *encryption*, not *hashing*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot "decrypt" a SHA-1 hash, it is a "*digest*" (or "*signature*") algorithm and not an *encryption* algorithm.

It is only possible to check whether some other text you have has the same signature, and in that regard SHA-1 is a very strong algorithm, albeit not without its weaknesses, particularly when used with low-entropy source data such as passwords.

Comment: Sorry, I thought SHA-1 was not a that strong algorithm, or am I wrong? I mean, there are huge databases with them

Comment: @DannyCruzeira it's strong in the sense that it's not possible to _algorithmically_ reverse the digest, nor find another text which has the same signature.  The existence of databases of plaintext -> digest pairs does not intrinsically weaken the algorithm, only its (mis)use as a password "encryption" method.

Comment: That entirely depends on the use case. Are you hashing sensible data? Then yes, SHA-1 is weak.

Comment: "Strong" is a pretty meaningless word in this case. The suitability of SHA1 is entirely dependent what you're trying to use it for. And @Dan, no, SHA1 is not weak for hashing *sensitive* data. SHA1 is actually very good for this purpose. It is fundamentally impossible to get the sensitive data back from a hash. You may find some other value which produces the *same* hash, but you have in no way recovered the sensitive data that produced the original hash. Why you would be hashing sensitive data in the first place is a mystery, except to detect tampering or change between versions.

Comment: @Dan it is too weak to be used in signatures, otherwise it is still pretty strong, e.g. for key derivation it is fine, although SHA-2 should of course be preferred.

Comment: As I said. Entirely depends on what you want to do with the hashes. I suggest having a watch at ircmaxell's talk about hashing in PHP. http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/10/password-hashing-in-php-talk.html#more

Comment: Wow.. Let me start by saying. IDGAF about how strong sha1 is, or even whether or not it can be straight up decrypted. I wanted to know if a function or method existed to apply a passphrase to an encrypted string. send "sandwich" to sha1() with passphrase "doggy", then later, send sha1 back to "sandwich" using passphrase "doggy".

Comment: @DylanLarrity no, there is no such method.  What you are describing is _decryption_, which per my first paragraph is impossible when using a _one way hashing algorithm_.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no way to decrypt a SHA-1 hash since SHA-1 is only a one-way hash method. If people were able to decrypt those then SHA-1 wouldn't be a very safe hashing algorithm method at all.

Comment: It's not an encryption method, it's a hashing algorithm.

Comment: Corrected my answer, thank you for the heads up :)

Comment: I can't vote this up. While true, you've simply stated what the question already states. He's not *trying* to decrypt SHA1, he knows you can't do that. He's looking for a reversible alternative.

Comment: @owlstead I know it's not a key, I just commit the mistake of naming everything that can be hashed, a "key" which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a large difference between hashing and encryption.

Hashing is meant to be one-way. That means once you hash something it will only exist as a hash and you should not be able to determine the input from the output. SHA-1 is one of these.

For encryption however you want to do exactly that. There's different ways of achieving this as well. You can work with symmetric or asymmetric encryption. The difference is that for symmetric encryption you need the same key for encrypting and decrypting data. Examples for this are DES and AES. Asymmetric encryption has different keys for encrypting and decrypting data. You can also use those for signing data. Examples for this are RSA or ElGamal.